# Vertical align top SELECT vs TEXTAREA

Tags: html, alignment

I want to know how to get these two elements to vertically align. The approach highlighted below doesn't work. See a [live demo here](http://www.electronrock.com/php/test1.php).

```
<?php
$w.="<html><head><title>Activity</title></head><body>\n";
$w.="<form action={$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]} method=post>\n";
$w.="<select name=listbox1 style=\"height:20px; width:100px\" vertical-align:top>\n";
$w.=" <option value=value1>option1</option>\n";
$w.=" <option value=value2>option2</option>\n";
$w.=" <option value=value3>option3</option>\n";
$w.="</select>\n";
$w.="<textarea name=value2 style=\"height:20px; width:200px\" vertical-align:top></textarea></br>\n";
$w.="</form></body></html>";
echo $w;
?>
```

Comment: Please tag this question with HTML, as the fact that you generate it with PHP is of little importance here.

Comment: Instead of `</select>\n`, do `</select><br />`

Comment: add display: block; to the elements and they will be each in a new line. https://jsfiddle.net/4jecstys/1/

Comment: your codes line number four and nine $w.="<select name=listbox1 style=\"height:20px; width:100px; vertical-align:top\">\n"; enclosing double quotes went wrong.

Comment: The PHP code is completely irrelevant noise. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You missplaced the closing quotes in styles both in the select and in the textarea:

```
 style=\"height:20px; width:100px\" vertical-align:top>
```

To

```
style=\"height:20px; width:100px vertical-align:top\">
```

Full script

```
<?php
    $w.="<html><head><title>Activity</title></head><body>\n";
    $w.="<form action={$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]} method=post>\n";
    $w.="<select name=listbox1 style=\"height:20px; width:100px; vertical-align:top\">\n"; //This line edited
    $w.=" <option value=value1>option1</option>\n";
    $w.=" <option value=value2>option2</option>\n";
    $w.=" <option value=value3>option3</option>\n";
    $w.="</select>\n";
    $w.="<textarea name=value2 style=\"height:20px; width:200px vertical-align:top\"></textarea></br>\n"; //This line edited
    $w.="</form></body></html>";
    echo $w;
?>
```

Comment: Holy misplaced quotation mark, I can't BELIEVE I didn't see that.
Thank you ameenulla0007, Marcos, Yavuz.

Comment: Hey. I just noticed my original post was edited by others. I didn't know they could do that. This is like a... technical forum Wiki. Interesting!    I can't upvote yet I'm too new it won't let me.

Comment: Yes, exactly, they can do that, you can mark an accepted answer checking the "check" icon at the left of an answer.

Comment: There's so much php help on the web, I haven't had to ask much here.  I just started learning it.  I wrote a script that creates a randomized set of evenly-ranked volleyball teams and captains, we use it at tournaments. Works on my desktop and mobile phone. Script checks for mobile browser to optimize display format.  php is great. The tournament thing was tricky but worked out perfectly. I'm an EE not a developer.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
<?php
        $w.="<html><head><title>Activity</title></head><body>\n";
        $w.="<form action={$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]} method=post>\n";
        $w.="<select name=listbox1 style=\"height:20px; width:100px; vertical-align:top\">\n";
        $w.=" <option value=value1>option1</option>\n";
        $w.=" <option value=value2>option2</option>\n";
        $w.=" <option value=value3>option3</option>\n";
        $w.="</select>\n";
        $w.="<textarea name=value2 style=\"height:20px; width:200px; vertical-align:top\"></textarea></br>\n";
        $w.="</form></body></html>";
        echo $w;
        ?>
```